# delete two models with foreign key in one function

Tags: model, foreign-keys, yii2, relationship

I want to delete two models in one function. But this model has relationship i tried to do that like this:

```
public function actionDelete($id) {
        $this->findModel($id);


        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }


    protected function findModel($id) {
        if (($model = UrUser::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        $RoyalUserData=$model->Rel_RoyalUserData;
        $data= UserData::find()->where(['Id' => $RoyalUserData])->one();
        if($model->delete() && $data->delete()){
        return $this->redirect(['index']);}
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
```

or this way:

```
 public function actionDelete($id) {

        $this->findModel($id)->delete();
        $this->findRoyalUserData($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    protected function findModel($id) {
        if (($model = UrUser::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
    protected function findRoyalUserData($id) {
        if (($model = UrUser::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        $RoyalUserData=$model->Rel_RoyalUserData;
        $data= UserData::find()->where(['Id' => $RoyalUserData])->one();

        return $data;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('data not exist.');
        }
    }
```

But when i delete first Model i have

> throw new NotFoundHttpException('data not exist.');

becouse I try to refer to an object that no longer exists because it has just been removed. On the other side when i first tried to remove RoyalUserData I have foreing key error. What should i do to delete this models at the same time?

Comment: Can you explain this relationship? I'm seeing three tables here and you want to delete just 2 of them, is that correct? What's the relashionship between `UrUser`, `RoyalUserData`, `UserData`?

Answer (score 0):

Swap the deletion order. First delete the child model and then the parent model:

```
$data = UserData::find()->where(['Id' => $RoyalUserData])->one();
if ($data->delete() && $model->delete()) {
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

Comment: `Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails `

Comment: Then you have another record that has the same foreign key. You need to delete all the child records before you can delete the parent.